# why isn't my search working?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get the php code to search the database and return all the matching "park_name"s but it says that the search variable is undefined and also only returns one park from the database.
This is the code I have for the search:

```
<form method="post" action="Search_page.php" name="search" id="Search">
<label for="search">Search:</label><input type="text" name="Search" id="search" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$search = $_POST['search'];
$search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search); }
$sql="SELECT Park_name, street FROM park_list WHERE park_name LIKE '%$search%'"; 
//query db
$result = $db->query($sql);
?>
</div>
<?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<div class="results">
<h2><?php echo $row['Park_name']?></h2> </br>
<p><?php echo $row['street']?></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `Search` !== `search`

Comment: Try to interrupt your string and concat. Or add {} like this : " '%{$search}%' "

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Grace; I'm not sure if you saw any of the answers, but I did notice something else about your code to which I did made a new edit to it and you will need to [reload my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44285064/1415724) in order to see what was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, `Search` != `search`.

Error reporting told you about it too.

- Btw, `!=` is the logical operator for "does not equal" ;-)

Those are case-sensitive.

By the way; do yourself a favor and use a prepared statement if you want to save/keep your database.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

and check for errors on the query, should it fail using `mysqli_error($db)`.

You're also using a name attribute here in conjunction with the POST array of the same name:

```
<form method="post" action="Search_page.php" name="search" id="Search">
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                             Remove that ^
```

and rename `name="Search"` for the input to `name="search"`.

where you thought would pan out, which it won't. Your search is relying on the input's name attribute (and the input itself). Forms generally do not use name attributes.

- You need to remove it.

Side note: It's usually best to use a `!empty()` < (not empty) for a user input, instead of `isset()`. The latter is mostly used for radios/checkboxes/submit inputs.

Comment: this is helpful but the results section only display one results and shows before I searched, do you know how i might fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Form field names are case sensitive.

Change your second line to

```
<label for="search">Search:</label><input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have rep to comment yet, but Park_name should be lowercase.
You have inconsistent case in the sql statement:

```
$sql="SELECT Park_name, street FROM park_list WHERE park_name LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Comment: `Park_name`? Thats the column name.

Comment: column names in a query and most of the time are not case-sensitive and will only depend on the db's collation, only in a loop will they be

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Yea, I looked into it and @Fred-ii- is right. The syntax for the statement should be `SELECT <column1> FROM <table_name> WHERE <column1> LIKE '%".$search."%'`. But column names are not case-sensitive. On unix/linux table and database names are. And on windows neither table, database, nor column names are case sensitive.

Comment: @JayBlanchard of course you don't want to be dynamically building queries. He should be using prepared statements as Fred -ii- suggests. But the discussion here is more centered on the inconsistent case, which makes the statement less readable and more confusing for someone trying to debug it

Comment: I get that, but let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices (an ongoing battle in PHP answers on Stack). If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: I will concede that my answer would have been more apt as a comment. But as I explained in the answer, I do not yet have enough reputation to comment. Nevertheless, I do feel like my answer led to a useful dialog on the importance of consistent case, and I see nothing wrong with supplementing existing answers on the importance of PDO statements with the importance of consistent casing and clean code.

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) And you could improve your answer to  A.) demonstrate more consistent case and 2.) show the correct concepts for administering the query. Just trying to help you construct better answers. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Stack Overflow is not about useful dialog, that is not how it is set up. It *is* about useful answers.